# Pivot table without aggregation and multiple pivot columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, pivot

I've got this situation where I think the best solution is using a pivot function, but I don't really know how to. Or maybe there is a much better way to do this...

I got this table as a source :

```
ID   | version | code | property | value
-----|---------|------|----------|------
  110|        1|    AA|     prop1|    10
  110|        1|    AA|     prop2|    20
  110|        1|    AA|     prop3|    30
  110|        1|    BB|     prop1|    10
  110|        1|    BB|     prop2|    40
  110|        1|    BB|     prop3|    20
  110|        2|    AA|     prop1|    50
  120|        1|    BB|     prop2|    60
  120|        2|    AA|     prop3|    80
```

What I want to end up with is the following :

```
ID   | version | code | prop1 | prop2 | prop3
-----|---------|------|-------|-------|------
  110|        1|    AA|     10|     20|    30
  110|        1|    BB|     10|     40|    20
  110|        2|    AA|     50|       |      
  120|        1|    BB|       |     60|      
  120|        2|    AA|       |       |    80
```

So you see I don't do aggregation, just a pivot over the first 3 tables.
Is this posible in TSQL, I'm using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Is it always `prop1`, `prop2` and `prop3`?

Comment: "No aggregation" is easily achieved if there will only ever be a maximum of one value in each group and you pick an aggregate which, if provided a single value, returns that same value - such as `SUM`, `MIN` or `MAX` (I generally prefer the latter two since they apply to a wider range of types)

Comment: @wewesthemenace Yes, the colums can be static

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want grouping on id, version and code, so it is simple pivot:

```
Select * from TableName
pivot(max(value) for property in([prop1],[prop2],[prop3]))p
```

If table has more columns then you will need to pick right columns first:

```
;with cte as(Select id, version, code, property, value from TableName)
Select * from cte
pivot(max(value) for property in([prop1],[prop2],[prop3]))p
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `property` is always `prop1`, `prop2` and `prop3`, you could do this using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
      ID
    , Version
    , Code
    , MAX(CASE WHEN Property = 'prop1' THEN VALUE END) AS [prop1]
    , MAX(CASE WHEN Property = 'prop2' THEN VALUE END) AS [prop2]
    , MAX(CASE WHEN Property = 'prop3' THEN VALUE END) AS [prop3]
FROM SampleData
GROUP BY ID, Version, Code
```

---

Here is a dynamic approach. Read this [**article**](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Crosstab/65048/) for reference.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/74490/1/0)

```
DECLARE @sql1 VARCHAR(4000) = ''
DECLARE @sql2 VARCHAR(4000) = ''
DECLARE @sql3 VARCHAR(4000) = ''

SELECT @sql1 = 
'SELECT
      ID
    , Version
    , Code
'

SELECT @sql2 = @sql2 +
'   , MAX(CASE WHEN Property = ''' + Property + ''' THEN VALUE END) AS [' + Property + ']' + CHAR(10)
FROM(
    SELECT DISTINCT Property FROM SampleData
)t
ORDER BY Property

SELECT @sql3 =
'FROM SampleData
GROUP BY ID, Version, Code
ORDER BY ID, Version, Code'

PRINT(@sql1 + @sql2 + @sql3)
EXEC (@sql1 + @sql2 + @sql3)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @t table (Id int,version int,code varchar(10),property varchar(10),val int)
insert into @t (Id,version,code,property,val)values (110,1,'AA','prop1',10),
(110,1,'AA','prop2',20),(110,1,'AA','prop3',30),(110,1,'BB','prop1',10),
(110,1,'BB','prop2',40),(110,1,'BB','prop3',20),(110,2,'AA','prop1',50),(120,1,'BB','prop2',60),
(120,1,'AA','prop3',80)


select Id,version,code,[prop1],[prop2],[prop3]
  from (
select ID,version,code,property,val 
    from @t )t
PIVOT(SUM(val)FOR Property IN ([prop1],[prop2],[prop3]))p
```